# Ограничения на ввод JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, intellij-idea, gui

Здравствуйте, столкнулся с проблемой при вводе в TextField данных. Необходимо разрешить ввод только латиницы. Прошу помощи в решении данной проблемы. Буду рад какой-либо информации!

Answer (score 0):

Первое что приходить в голову: после каждого нажатия клавиши в TextField, берешь текст из TextField (наверное так: `String text = tfMyText.getText()`), удаляешь из него все неразрешенные символы и возвращать обратно (наверное так: `tfMyText.setText(text )`). У меня нет возможности запустить JavaFX.

Answer (score 0):

Решил данную проблему так. Возможно не самый лучший вариант, но рабочий:

```
String word = txtEnter.getText();
 Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[\\W-\\d]");
 Matcher w= p.matcher(word);
 if(w.find()==true||c.find()==true)
 result.setText("Error")`
```